# Repeating (or not) "to" in a sentence involving infinitives set in parallel

Tags: infinitives, parallelism, conjunction-reduction

I googled it but I couldn't find the answer... maybe I didn't seek it in the proper way.

My question is if "to" must be repeated in sentences such as the following ones:

> - In the past, women used to do the housework and **to** take care of children.
> - The aim of this meeting is to control their progress and **to** discuss the new working plan.

If I had to bet, I would omit the second *to*... But I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases, the second *to* can be omitted; *to* introduces an infinitive phrase, and that infinitive phrase can include a compound verb. Hence, for example, *To Live and Die in L.A.* (the title of a movie from the 1980s), where *in L.A.* modifies *live and die*, and *to* introduces the whole thing.

In your second example, it's also fine to include the *to*. In essence, both of these are fine:

> The aim of this meeting is {to {control their progress and discuss the new working plan}}.
>   The aim of this meeting is {{to control their progress} and {to discuss the new working plan}.

(In the latter case, it might be better to say "The aims of this meeting are […]", but I think it's fine as-is.)

In your first example, however, I find it pretty awkward to include the *to*, because *used to* is an idiom, pronounced /ˈjuːstə/ (with a /s/ sound, not a /z/ like *used*), and I hardly feel that it contains the word *to* anymore; so the second *to* doesn't sound like a repetition of the already-occurring word *to*, but rather like a first occurrence of the word *to*. Granted, it doesn't sound anywhere near as bad as something like "In the past, women would do the housework and *to take care of children" (which is completely ungrammatical); but I would still find it surprising in modern American writing.

Comment: Agreed, a better construction would to remove the colloquialism *used to* entirely and say *In the past, women did the housework and took care of children.*

Comment: Thanks, ruakh. Concentrating on finding examples.

Comment: I'd say that the more semantically (or 'fix-phrasedly' in some cases) 'paired' (to bill and coo / to kiss and tell// to stand and watch [≅ phase structure, stand watching] > to live and die > to see and to believe ... [Places] to visit and to eat ...) the infinitives are, the greater the tendency ... perhaps in the extreme, the requirement ... to omit the second 'to'. 'To have and to hold' seems a counter-example, but again a fixed phrase, of the other kind.